# Register is not setting with buffer value in NASM x64

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm, cpu-registers

hope you can help me with that problem. I've to read data from an other file in nasm and I wanted to check the registers value with gdb but I found out that we can't so I hard coded the file value in a "String". I'm pretty sure I did something awful and that's why it isn't working but since I'm a beginner in nasm I am not able to find my mistake.

With that code, isn't eax supposed to be the value of the buffer ? (value of DebugStr in the example) ? Why do I see 0x31313130 ? I really hope you guys can help me

```
SECTION .data

    DebugStr: db "01111100 10101010 01111000", 10
    DebugStrLen: equ 32

SECTION .bss

SECTION .text

global _start

_start:
    xor     rax, rax             ; rax = 0
    xor     rbx, rbx             ; rbx = 0
    xor     rcx, rcx             ; rcx = 0
    xor     rdx, rdx             ; rdx = 0
    mov     r8, DebugStr         ; r8 = address of ReadBuffer
    mov     r9, Output           ; r9 = address of OutputBuffer

    ;mov rax, 0                  ; Specify sys_read call
    ;mov rdi, 0                  ; Specify File Descriptor 0: Standard Input
    ;mov rsi, r8                 ; Pass offset of the buffer to read to
    ;mov rdx, ReadBufferSize     ; Pass number of bytes to read at one pass
    ;syscall

    mov eax, [r8] ; eax = ReadBuffer value to eax = 01111100 10101010 01111000
```

Comment: How many byes (bits) does a register hold? Why would you think you could fit a 26-byte string in a 32-bit (4-byte) register? Doesn't it look like you load the register with the [ASCII Values](https://www.asciitable.com/) for `"1110"`? (which is where `0x31313130` comes from)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, you're clearly right. For the real example with the buffer, is the buffer containing a string or a binary ? If it is a string and I want to loop through all numbers, I will have to translate every character to binary and removing the spaces ?

Comment: The buffer contains the characters `'1'`, `'1'`, `',1'`, `'0'` (each character is 1-byte, 8-bits) which are the 4-bytes (32-bits) that will fit in `eax`. If you look at the link for those characters, you see the ASCII value for `'1'` is `0x31` and character `'0'` has the ASCII value `0x30`. That's why you see what you see.

Comment: Yeah, to turn that string into a binary number, you could `vmovdqu ymm0, [rel DebugStr]` / `vpslld ymm0, ymm0, 7` / `vpmovmskb eax, ymm0` to extract the high bits (shifted from low) of 32 bytes.  Or without AVX2, do it in 2 parts with SSE2.

Comment: Okay, thank's a lot guys. I didn't see it that way. That was kinda dumb of me to think it would be that easy. Thx !